# VS2010 TFS Build Failure-Could not complete the request to remote agent

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, tfs, iis-7.5

I received this error when trying to run a build from within VS2010.

`C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (3588): Web deployment task failed.(Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://http//[serverName]:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site'.)  Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://http//[serverName]:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site'. The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'`
I'm not sure why it says "https://http//..."
The code is checked in to a remote TFS server. I created a Build Definition from within VS Team Explorer and that is the error I get when trying to build/publish the project. The [servername] above is the IIS server to where my project is to be published.

These are the MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://[serverName] 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/[site/app Name]"
```

Anyone come across the same error?
btw, I was able to do a successful Web Deploy from within VS Publish itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edward solved the first part of your problem.

Regarding the https:// part, msdeploy defaults to doing things in a secure manner.  To turn this off you have to use the -allowUntrusted command.

for "light" reading:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx

and

http://forums.iis.net/t/1158582.aspx

Comment: 1. is there a way to add the allowUntrusted command to the TFS Build Definition? 2. it seems to work (just within the VS publish GUI) with http://[serverName] but not with ([serverName] and Allow Untrusted). I'm not sure if its my local machine or if the IIS server isnt config'd right b/c it doesn't seem to like using https

Comment: ok, so i added /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate (which is the equivalent of the aforementioned -allowUntrusted arg for the command prompt-thanks Chris), to the TFS Build def. config as well as /p:username and /p:password and so far so good...successful build/publish...Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that you either need to specify **just** a hostname to the `MSDeployServerUrl` option, or a full URL to msdeploy.  That is, either:

```
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://[servername]:8172/msdeploy.axd
```

or:

```
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=[servername]
```

The latter will be translated to `https://[servername]:8172/msdeploy.axd`.

Comment: ok..so atleast now it doesn't show `https://http//` in the error... but do you know why it's using https?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question being opened, but I came across same problem and it wasn't fully resolved with answers above...

What I needed to change was removing protocol from MSDeployServiceUrl

```
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=[servername]
```

AND changing MSDeployPublishMethod to RemoteAgent

```
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
```

Hope this will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Publish Profile using web deploy and saved in TFS and then in my build definition in MSBuild Arguments I added this:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=Web_Dev_WebDeployProfile  /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:username=myusername /p:Password=mypassword
```

It worked for me. I also make sure that my build has **permission** to the published folder (virtual directory)

I also make sure that **Web Management Service** and **Web Deployment Agent Service** are running on my web server.