# Team Build ignores MSBuild arguments

Tags: build, tfs

I have created a new team build definition. On every checkin, the build happens on a TFS server (another build controller). After the build completes, I want to publish the files. The MSBuild input arguments used are `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=QADeploy`. `QADeploy` is the publishing profile created.

I expect the team build to succeed which happens. But the successful build does not publish or attempt to publish the files to the destination folder. Any ideas why, the publish via publish profile is not triggered?

Comment: Nothing, the logs don't have any mention of publish.

Comment: Which build process template does this build definition use?

Comment: Is it meant to be deployed on your build controller server? What is the project you are building? What does QADeploy looking like?

Comment: @Torbjorn, I am using the default build process template

Comment: The QA deploy is a file system deploy. I copy the publish files to a shared folder in the QA environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Weird, but adding the Visual Studio Version resolved the problem:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=QADeploy /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was pulling my hair out. Check out this [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478747/auto-deploy-using-continuous-integration-in-tfs-2012), it helped me.

I fixed it via copying both WEB and WEB APPLICATION web build targets from this path on a PC with VS installed into the matching path on the build server:

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0
(path for VS 2012)

I am not sure if their suggestion of using the full installer for web deploy helps. I tried both suggestions at the same time and it worked there after.

Also it only works on a Web Project

Comment: I tried the MSBuild with the arguments I have supplied. MSBuild for some reason is not trying to publish.

Comment: Did you copy in the files specified in my answer?